# Dummy coding a variable as a factor? Cannot seem to work with a package

Tags: r, regression

Trying to use a more obscure package in my field of study. I am attempting to add a matrix of predictor variables. Wording in the package is as follows:

"An optional matrix of predictor variables for the time-intensity
parameters, where the columns represent the predictor variables. Cat-
egorical predictor variables need to be dummy coded."

Thus I convert into factors/characters which gives the following error which I attempt to solve in the code chunk (Xit_form being a 18x2 matrix of categorical variables)

"Error in crossprod(x, y) :
requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments "

```
xit_form[,1] <- as.factor(xit_form[,1])
xit_form[,2] <- as.factor(xit_form[,2])
mode(xit_form) <- "numeric"
```

however when i run this, the package does not seem to be treating it as a factor. Any way I can solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is completely off, but try `model.matrix`.

```
xit_form[] <- apply(xit_form, 2, factor)
model.matrix(~ 0 + ., data = as.data.frame(xit_form))
```

---

### Data

```
set.seed(2021)
xit_form <- matrix(sample(letters[1:4], 20, TRUE), ncol = 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

We may use `dummies` from `fastDummies`

```
library(fastDummies)
library(dplyr)
xit_form %>% 
   dummy_cols()
```